# Can anyone throw me some photograph ideas?

Tags: photography

In my graphic design course, we have been set a brief which requires us to go out and take 50 photographs of things that relate to this list of 50 sayings. I've got a fair amount done all ready, but there are still some challenging photographs to take.

I need help on the following:

Rebellion,
On the periphery,
Small-mindedness,
Impediment,
Encompassing,
One seizing power illegally,
Break-away faction,
Way of thinking,
Irrational fear,
Use a diving rod,
Without warning,
Peter out

Comment: Well I think that should be your ideas not ours for your homework? Taking pictures need time. Just give yourself this time!

Comment: I closed this question for several reasons.  1) Even though this is for your design class it is related to photography so it would be better suited on photography.se.  I didn't migrate your question because I do not think it would be op topic there.  You could try asking your question over there and see what happens.  2) This is too broad and will produce opinionated answers.  3) It does somewhat appear you're wanting us to do your homework and come up with ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a dictionary and thesaurus to give a start to ideas. 
You can also go the other way from Vicki's suggestion above and be very 'Staged' - Set up some shoots (think about the type of graphics you see on graphics/photo libraries and be obvious - i.e. A guy in a T-shirt that says 'Peter')

Sounds like a fun brief!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different approach to fill in the rest of your list.

Instead of trying to think of specific things to photograph, you could walk around town and take pictures of everything interesting you could find, focusing on things that are normally ignorable; the way the top of a building looks against the sky when you look strait up at it, trash on the street, plants growing in between cracks in the sidewalk, people back-lit by the sun, an empty parking lot, etc.

Take a TON of shots, and then pick ones to match up to your remaining list of words.

This approach would be similar to if you were working with a client and you didn't have the luxury of hiring a photographer to take specific photos to fit your design perfectly, and you had to sort through stock photos to pick what fits best.